# Intersection and union between two context-free languages

Tags: context-free-grammar

It has been difficult for me to demonstrate these two exercises, I hope they can help me.

[this is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABW2d.png)

I think the union is a free-context language.

Comment: CFGs are closed unser union but not under intersection. Try this link: http://www.cs.nuim.ie/~jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node43.html

Comment: Standard example is $a^nb^nc^*$ and $a^*b^nc^n$